# В предложении " о как прекрасно жить!" нужно после "о" ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении "о как прекрасно жить!" нужно после "о" ставить запятую?

Answer (score 1):

**В большинстве случаев между частицами О и КАК ставится запятая и делается пауза**, однако возможны исключения. В приведенном примере отсутствие запятой возможно как вариант, если ударение падает на "прекрАсно":

**"О как прекрАсно просто жить!** Встречать рассветы, провожать закаты..."

Однако изменение структуры предложения (просто уменьшение объема фразы) часто ведет к необходимости сделать паузу: **О, как прекрасно жить!** О, как прекрасно просто жить, Лет не считать, не чувствовать усталость, Растить сады или детей растить, Чтоб всё на свете снова повторялось!

**Другие примеры:**

О, как прекрасно было тогда небо!

О, этот Юг, о, эта Ницца!.. О, как их блеск меня тревожит! Жизнь, как подстреленная птица, Подняться хочет — и не может.

О, как торжествовал бы Иван, если бы следователь явился к нему пораньше...

Answer (score 0):

О небо, о боги мои... И так далее (яду мне, яду!) Или: о мой застенчивый герой! Видите, везде обращения. Здесь запятая не ставится. А вот в вашем случае ставится. Здесь у вас "о" в значении "ах".

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm
101. Обращение

Естественно, это не связано ни с какими "паузами" и "ударениями", на которые так любит напирать @Sibylla, при этом никогда не давая ни одного пруфа.

Comment: Удивительно, но Розенталь с Вами почему-то не согласен, тоже любит говорить о какой-то интонации:  "Омонимичные частицы и междометия (о, ах, а) различаются следующим образом: частица имеет усилительное значение и от обращения интонационно не отделяется (не имеет самостоятельного УДАРЕНИЯ); напротив, междометия интонационно самостоятельны, ударны, после них имеется ПАУЗА. Ср.: О поле мое заветное, ты сейчас отдыхаешь после жатвы (Айтм.) — О, ветер! О, снежные бури! (Бл.).

Comment: Кстати, междометие - это часть речи, выражающая, но не называющая эмоции, поэтому О никак не может равняться АХ. АХ. I. межд. 1. Выражает испуг, внезапное удивление, восхищение, сожаление, возмущение и т.п.

Comment: Почитайте справочник -то.